# ¿Hay alguna forma de trabajar con struts2 o servlets sin reiniciar servidor?

Tags: java, servidor, struts2

Existe alguna forma de estar trabajando en un servidor java, ya sea con struts2 o servlets, y no tener que reiniciar el server cada vez que haces algun cambio en el backend?

es decir pongamos que modifico algo en la clase LibroBO o en el servlet modificarLibro, y que no haga falta reiniciar el server para refrescar los cambios.

Es que tarda dos horas en iniciarse el dichoso servidor cada vez que cambio o añado codigo.

Comment: No nos comentas que servidor es, ni que versión, así es muy difícil ayudar

Comment: Apatche Tomcat, eclipse